# how to show a loading page for some n seconds

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want to show some loading content for some seconds then I want to show the first page, loading page content some thing lik

```
<div class="well-bgs">Loading..</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I'll guess...

```
    $.mobile.pageLoading(); 

//when it's loaded          
    $.mobile.pageLoading( true );
```

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/api/methods.html